# Найти популярные маршруты. (sql order by count 2 columns)

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите плиз,
есть таблица с маршрутами
там, понятно, id, еще всякие поля но нас интересует 
города откуда и куда

[image: пример таблицы]

Задача. Выбрать 15 самых популярных маршрутов. То есть count у которых 
больше. Но заминка в том, что я не могу понять как это сделать 
именно по 2 полям. То есть примерно вывод ожидаю следующий
Москва - Санкт-Петербург
Санкт-Петербург - Москва
И так далее по популярности. 
Отдельно, например куда с москвы ездят самое большее, 
могу выбрать, а вот именно по 2 полям не получается.
Помогите, плиз

[image: вот вывод если по айди искать]

[image: вот структура с айди]

[image: вот скрин]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первое что в голову приходит, `union select town_to town_from, town_from town_to`

Comment: Покажите требуемый ответ на ЭТИХ данных. Скажем, для 3, а не 15, самых-самых... Навскидку `SELECT town_from, town_to
    FROM table
    GROUP BY town_from, town_to
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 15`, а если не оно - уточняйте постановку задачи

Comment: SELECT town_from, town_to FROM table GROUP BY town_from, town_to ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 15

Comment: так вроде хорошо. но у меня найди городов вообще то, в начале задачи не стал писать, чтоб не путать, но вот какая странность. Когда переделал ваш запрос под айди, то есть написал SELECT town_from, town_to, COUNT(*) FROM trip GROUP BY from_id, to_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 15   то  вывело как то странно, я к вопросу картинку прикреплю, тут никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас огромное количество записей в данных, где from_id и to_id равны 0.  Поэтому группировка по Id не дает результата.
Вообще это не очень хорошая идея хранить и название города и его код в одной таблице. Лучше таблица с городами, а в таблице с поездками их коды.

Вот запрос, который решает вашу задачу

```
select 
 town_from, town_to, count(id) as total 
from 
 trip 
group by 
 town_from, town_to 
order by 
 total DESC;
```

Результат

```
Москва  Минск   301
минск   москва  231
Москва  Санкт-Петербург 165
Санкт-Петербург Москва  160
санкт-петербург минск   100
```

Comment: вы под t_from  и t_to подразумеваете town_from и town_to? То есть строковые поля? если да, то что вот такой вывод непонятный.

Comment: bFrom bTo count(*)
0 0 19473
0 2 1
0 3 1
0 7 2
0 9 3
0 20 1
0 22 2
0 27 1
0 28 1
0 49 2
0 51 1
0 60 1
0 72 1
0 250 1
0 847 1
2 40 1

Comment: здесь не внятно, я в вопрос скрин добавлю

Comment: Я подразумеваю числа, коды городов.

Comment: с айдишниками тоже не нормально совсем. скрин в вопрос добавлю

Comment: Добавьте сортировку по полю count(*)

Comment: Я понял так, что маршрут Москва-Питер и Питер-Москва это один и тот же?

Comment: нет, питер москва и москва питер это разные

Comment: Тут проблема, что не видно ни структуры вашей таблицы ни данных которые в ней. Вы пишите, что результат странный, а кроме вас никто эту странность увидеть не может. Приложите данные.

Comment: а как тут приложить sql файл?

Comment: Ссыку на хранилище, гугл или яндекс

Comment: http://abriss.pro/trip.sql

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia Очень грязные данные. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Айди сейчас нет, будут добавляться, и имена городов в другой таблице уже. Так и будет, поэтому я и хотел по айди  искать. просто  по началу писали как хотели, сейчас город только выбрать можно.

Comment: По айди же так же выбирать, только соответственно айди подставлять а не названия в запрос. Да?

Comment: Да, конечно. Тут группировка по двум любым полям